# kotlin coroutines don't work in a command line

Tags: kotlin, jvm, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinc

I have the following program:

```
//Main.kt
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.concurrent.*

fun main() {
        val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Default)

        scope.launch{
                println("hello")
        }
}
```

I tried to run it in a command line:

```
i@LAPTOP:/mnt/d/PROJECTS$ ls
Main.kt  annotations-23.0.0.jar  kotlin-stdlib-1.9.21.jar  kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.8.0-RC2.jar
i@LAPTOP:/mnt/d/PROJECTS$ kotlinc Main.kt -cp annotations-23.0.0.jar:kotlin-stdlib-1.9.21.jar:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.8.0-RC2.jar
i@LAPTOP:/mnt/d/PROJECTS$ java -cp annotations-23.0.0.jar:kotlin-stdlib-1.9.21.jar:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.8.0-RC2.jar:. MainKt
i@LAPTOP:/mnt/d/PROJECTS$
```

I expected to see *hello* in the command line but for some reason my program prints nothing. **Why?**

Answer (score 2):

This is because you launched the coroutine in the background and immediately finished running your application, so the coroutine didn't even have a chance to start executing.

If you want to wait for the coroutine to finish, use `runBlocking` instead of `launch`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        println("hello")
    }
}
```

You can also simply do `Thread.sleep(1000)` after launching, but generally we shouldn't assume an asynchronous task will take a specific amount of time.